# monitoring clipboard data

Tags: visual-c++, service, visual-studio-2012, clipboard

I want to write interrupt based console application or windows service for monitoring changed data in clipboard.So it would listen the clipboard data changed event. I have tried this using polling based but it is not efficient. So is there any way to achive this? Thank you.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649033%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have several articles on this, including common pitfalls to avoid.
http://www.clipboardextender.com/developing-clipboard-aware-programs-for-windows